# css chaning the z-index is not affectable

Tags: html, css

This is the result:
[image]

see how the link is over the numbers

I tried changing the z-index of the `before` element and keep making it larger, but the line keep above the numbers,

could u help please?
the code of the line is

```
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: 0; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
```

this is a jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FkSH5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `::before` pseudo-element (by the way, you should use `::` for pseudo-elements and `:` for pseudo-classes) is being overlaid by the `::after` pseudo-element.

The solution is to set the `::before` pseudo-element to be **relatively positioned** (if you don't use relative positioning, the z-index property will be ignored) with a z-index higher than the `::after` counterpart, i.e.:

```
#progressbar li::before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

See modified fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/FkSH5/1/

Comment: +1 it works, do you suggest to replace all my `:` with `::` ?

Comment: Only for pseudo-elements, `::before` and `::after`. However browsers are still able to recognize `:before` and `:after` without an issue, at least for now :)